# SwiftUI - Dynamic List filtering animation flies to right side when data source is empty

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have a `List` that gets data from my `people` array and displays their names.

I'm also filtering the list so that it only shows the names that contain the text field's text, which is `searchText`. Here's my code:

```
struct Person: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID() /// required for the List
    
    var name = ""
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var searchText = ""
    
    var people = [ /// the data source
        Person(name: "Alex"),
        Person(name: "Ally"),
        Person(name: "Allie"),
        Person(name: "Bob"),
        Person(name: "Tim"),
        Person(name: "Timothy")
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            TextField("Search here", text: $searchText) /// text field
            .padding()
            
            List {
                ForEach(
                    people.filter { person in /// filter the people
                        searchText.isEmpty || person.name.localizedStandardContains(searchText)
                    }
                ) { person in
                    Text(person.name)
                }
            }
            .animation(.default) /// add the animation
        }
    }
}
```

Without `.animation(.default)`, it doesn't animate the changes (as expected).

<kbd>[image: Filtering without animation]</kbd>

***With*** `.animation(.default)`, it animates!

<kbd>[image: Filtering with animation]</kbd>

However, the problem happens when none of the people's names contain `searchText`. When this happens, the `people.filter` returns an empty array, and the `List` freaks out. For example, when I type "q", this happens:

<kbd>[image: List zooms to the right]</kbd>

The entire list flies to the right, and zooms back in from the left when I delete "q". **How can I prevent this from happening?** I'm looking for a similar animation to the normal filtering animation (sliding up and disappearing, like in the second gif), or just fading it out.

### Edit: iOS 13

I just tested on iOS 13 and if I remove `.animation(.default)`, it works perfectly!

[image: Desired animation on iOS 13]

However, if I add `.animation(.default)` again, I get the same result as in iOS 14.

[image: Same result as iOS 14]

### Edit: List with sections + [@mahan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8292178/mahan)'s answer

My actual code groups the people, so I **already** use `sections` in my `List`.

```
struct Group: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID() /// required for the List
    
    var groupName = ""
    var people = [Person]()
}

struct Person: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID() /// required for the List
    
    var name = ""
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var searchText = ""

    /// groups of people
    var groups = [
        Group(groupName: "A People", people: [
            Person(name: "Alex"),
            Person(name: "Ally"),
            Person(name: "Allie")
        ]),
        Group(groupName: "B People", people: [
            Person(name: "Bob")
        ]),
        Group(groupName: "T People", people: [
            Person(name: "Tim"),
            Person(name: "Timothy")
        ])
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            TextField("Search here", text: $searchText) /// text field
            .padding()
            
            List {
                
                ForEach(

                    /// Filter the groups for people that match searchText
                    groups.filter { group in
                        searchText.isEmpty || group.people.contains(where: { person in
                            person.name.localizedStandardContains(searchText)
                        })
                    }
                ) { group in
                    Section(header: Text(group.groupName)) {
                        ForEach(

                            /// filter the people in each group
                            group.people.filter { person in
                                searchText.isEmpty || person.name.localizedStandardContains(searchText)
                            }
                        ) { person in
                            Text(person.name)
                        }
                    }
                }
                
            }
            .animation(.default) /// add the animation
        }
    }
}
```

<kbd>[image: sorting List with sections]</kbd>

If I wrap the `ForEach` inside the `List` as @mahan suggested, this happens:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

The `List` animates perfectly with no weird zoom animation, but the section headers lose their styles and look like normal rows. But I think we're getting close!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap **ForEach** in a **Section**, and the issue will be fixed.

```
        List {
            Section {
                ForEach(
                    people.filter { person in /// filter the people
                        searchText.isEmpty || person.name.localizedStandardContains(searchText)
                    }
                ) { person in
                    Text(person.name)
                }
            }
        }
        .animation(.default) /// add the animation
```

---

#### Update

You can add as many sections as you wish so.

```
struct Person: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID() /// required for the List
    
    var name = ""
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var searchText = ""
    
    var people = [ /// the data source
        Person(name: "Alex"),
        Person(name: "Ally"),
        Person(name: "Allie"),
        Person(name: "Bob"),
        Person(name: "Tim"),
        Person(name: "Timothy")
    ]
    
    var people2 = [ /// the data source
        Person(name: "John"),
        Person(name: "George"),
        Person(name: "Jack"),
        Person(name: "Mike"),
        Person(name: "Barak"),
        Person(name: "Steve")
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            TextField("Search here", text: $searchText) /// text field
                .padding()
            
            List {
                Section {
                    ForEach(
                        people.filter { person in /// filter the people
                            searchText.isEmpty || person.name.localizedStandardContains(searchText)
                        }
                    ) { person in
                        Text(person.name)
                    }
                }
                
                Section {
                    ForEach(people2.filter { person in /// filter the people
                        searchText.isEmpty || person.name.localizedStandardContains(searchText)
                    }) { person in
                        Text(person.name)
                    }
                }
            }
            .animation(.default) /// add the animation
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, if I wrap it in a `Section`, I can't have any more sections inside. Instead, they all get combined into one big section. I'll edit my question.

Comment: @aheze, You can have as many Sections as you wish so. You can add footer and header for them to differentiate them.

Comment: I got a weird result (the header looked the exact same as the row). I'm in school right now but will update by question ASAP

Comment: Edited my question.

Comment: Hmm, I checked your **Update** and replaced `groups.filter { group in ... }` in my edit with just `groups`. This works alright, but if the section doesn't contain any people, the header still shows up. [Gif](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aheze/DeveloperAssets/master/sectionsPreserved.gif)

Comment: That is because you do not  filter empty Groups. By the way, the problem is completly different than what you had asked. Better to ask another if you can not solve the issue.  @aheze

Comment: Well actually in my edit I filtered them, but I get the zoom animation.

Comment: After iOS 16.4.1, my list would not animate data changes. After hours of trying anything, this was the only thing that worked. Amazing that iOS updates can break AppStore apps that were supposed to be stable.