# SwiftUI - Prevent Sections from flying/zooming to the right in List when dynamically filtering them

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I originally asked this question:

[SwiftUI - Dynamic List filtering animation flies to right side when data source is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65065406/14351818)

There, I had a `List` without sections. I was filtering them so that it only showed the rows that contained the text inside a `TextField`. The solution was to wrap everything inside the `List` in a `Section`.

Unfortunately, I now need to filter `Section`s. Here's my code:

```
struct Group: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID() /// required for the List
    
    var groupName = ""
    var people = [Person]()
}
struct Person: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID() /// required for the List
    
    var name = ""
}
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var searchText = ""

    var groups = [
        Group(groupName: "A People", people: [
            Person(name: "Alex"),
            Person(name: "Ally"),
            Person(name: "Allie")
        ]),
        Group(groupName: "B People", people: [
            Person(name: "Bob")
        ]),
        Group(groupName: "T People", people: [
            Person(name: "Tim"),
            Person(name: "Timothy")
        ])
    ]

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            TextField("Search here", text: $searchText) /// text field
                .padding()
            
            List {
                ForEach(
                    
                    /// Filter the groups for those that contain searchText
                    groups.filter { group in
                        searchText.isEmpty || group.groupName.localizedStandardContains(searchText)
                    }
                    
                ) { group in
                    Section(header: Text(group.groupName)) {
                        ForEach(group.people) { person in
                            Text(person.name)
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            .animation(.default) /// apply the animation
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

<kbd>[image: filtering sections causes them to fly away]</kbd>

I pass in a filtered array in the `ForEach` to determine the `Section`s. However, whenever that array changes, the `List` animates really weirdly. The `Section`s zoom/fly to the right side, and come back from the left when the array includes them again. **How can I avoid this animation?**

If I remove `.animation(.default)`, it doesn't animate at all, as expected. But, **I would still like an animation**. Is there a way to fade the changes, or slide them instead?

Comment: @Yodagama I'm not applying a `.transition` anywhere... does List do that by default?

Comment: Yet another swiftui bug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is not using List. As long as you're not using selection and row deleting a ScrollView is basically the same.

If you want to style it a bit like the List that's also not that hard:

```swift
struct SearchAnimationExample: View {

    ...

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            TextField("Search here", text: $searchText) /// text field
                .padding()
            
            ScrollView {
                VStack(spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach(
                        groups.filter { group in
                            searchText.isEmpty || group.groupName.localizedStandardContains(searchText)
                        }
                    ) { group in
                        Section(header: header(title: group.groupName)) {
                            ForEach(group.people) { person in
                                row(for: person)
                                Divider()
                            }
                        }
                        
                    }.transition(.opacity) // Set which transition you would like
                    
                    // Always full width
                    HStack { Spacer() }
                }
            }
            .animation(.default) 
        }
    }
    
    func header(title: String) -> some View {
        HStack {
            Text(title).font(.headline)
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.4))
    }
        
    func row(for person: Person) -> some View {
        HStack {
            Text(person.name)
            Spacer()
        }.padding()
    }
}
```

Looks practically the same as the default list:

[image]

Comment: Ah nice! But you can't apply list styles, right? For example `InsetGroupedListStyle`

Comment: Also it doesn't seem to animate on iOS 13... [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hgjIstAQjIbZAcEDGuUQZTA5mnFxw66l/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Warning: ScrollView and HStack/VStack don't reuse views, which can cause memory issues and lag, so I don't recommend this as a replacement of a list with hundreds of rows. Ideally, if you want to avoid Lists altogether, you should use LazyHStacks and LazyVStacks (however, unfortunately, they are only available from iOS 14).

Comment: Oh that iOS 13 not animating is interesting. Never seen that happen. Yeah no list styles.

Comment: Weird to find this answer as accepted, since a VStack is NOT a List. No cell re-using, no deletion, etc. ... This is a workaround at its best, when you don't have many items, otherwise, for dynamic content, it is not the way to go. Original question stays unanswerd, as I have the same problem.

Comment: @SteffenFunke Well you could probably use LazyStack for the cell reusing.