# SwiftUI list animations looks strange

Tags: list, animation, swiftui

my SwiftUI animations for a list looks strange:
[image]

I use nearly the default border plate code from the CoreData starter project in Xcode 12.5:

```
struct ListView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.date, ascending: true)])
    private var items: FetchedResults<Item>
    
    @State private var isShowingScanner = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    Text("Item at \(item.timestamp, formatter: itemFormatter)")
                }
                .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
            }
            .navigationTitle("List")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    EditButton()
                    // ...                    
                }
                
            }
        }
    }

    private func deleteItems(offsets: IndexSet) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Any hint why this is happening?

Comment: Maybe check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65065406/swiftui-dynamic-list-filtering-animation-flies-to-right-side-when-data-source

Comment: This suggestion in this post with the Section does not work